# Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.ts(2322)

Tags: typescript, next.js, tsx, react-tsx

Through error message "Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'" typically arises in React components when JSX elements receive props that aren't recognized or expected. This error specifically denotes a mismatch between the expected properties and the actual props received by a JSX element, often related to rendering child components or applying properties incorrectly within React components.

I attempted to render a React component with certain props, including 'children' and 'className'. However, the error "Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'" appeared. I expected the component to render without any TypeScript error related to unrecognized props or attributes.

here my codebase...!

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes, { Requireable } from "prop-types";

interface TypographyProps {
  variant: "h1" | "h2" | "h3" | "h4" | "h5" | "h6" | "p" | "p1" | "p2";
  children: React.ReactNode;
  className?: string;
  font?: string;
}

const Typography: React.FC<TypographyProps> = ({
  variant,
  children,
  className,
  font,
  ...restProps
}) => {
  const variantMapping = {
    h1: {
      variant: "h1",
      classes:
        "2xl:text-[64px] lg:text-5xl md:text-4xl sm:text-3xl text-2xl leading-normal  font-lato_bold",
    },
    h2: {
      variant: "h2",
      classes:
        "2xl:text-5xl  lg:text-3xl md:text-2xl text-xl font-lato font-bold",
    },
    h3: {
      variant: "h3",
      classes:
        "2xl:text-4xl lg:text-2xl md:text-xl text-lg  font-lato font-bold",
    },
    h4: {
      variant: "h4",
      classes:
        "2xl:text-[32px]  lg:text-xl sm:text-lg text-lg  font-lato !font-bold ",
    },
    h5: {
      variant: "h5",
      classes:
        "2xl:text-2xl md:text-lg sm:text-base text-sm  font-lato font-medium ",
    },
    h6: {
      variant: "h6",
      classes: "2xl:text-xl  lg:text-base text-sm font-lato font-medium",
    },
    p: {
      variant: "p",
      classes:
        "2xl:text-lg xl:text-base md:text-sm  text-xs  font-lato font-medium",
    },
    p1: {
      variant: "p",
      classes: "2xl:text-base md:text-sm text-xs font-lato font-regular ",
    },
    p2: {
      variant: "p",
      classes: "2xl:text-sm text-xs font-lato font-regular ",
    },
  };

  const classes = variantMapping[variant]?.classes || "";
  const Component = variantMapping[variant]?.variant || "p";

  return (
    <Component className={`${classes} ${className}`} {...restProps}>
      {children}
    </Component>
  );
};
Typography.propTypes = {
  variant: PropTypes.oneOf([
    "h1",
    "h2",
    "h3",
    "h4",
    "h5",
    "h6",
    "p",
    "p1",
    "p2",
  ]).isRequired as Requireable<TypographyProps["variant"]>,
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
  className: PropTypes.string,
};
   

Typography.defaultProps = {
  className: "",
  variant: "h3" as TypographyProps["variant"],
};

export default Typography;
```

Comment: Hi, Muhammad. Through your complex variant mapping you seem to be creating a Component which is a string. I think maybe the error you are getting is the same as, for example, trying to create a component like `const foo = () => <p>hello</p>; return <"foo">` when you actually mean `; return <foo>`. I believe a component has to be a class or function.

Comment: Actually now I'm doubting myself from looking at https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html which says `When an element type starts with a lowercase letter, it refers to a built-in component like <div> or <span> and results in a string 'div' or 'span' passed to React.createElement`

Comment: What line is reporting the error?

Comment: Error:
Type '{ children: ReactNode; accept?: string | undefined; acceptCharset?: string | undefined; action?: string | ((formData: FormData) => void) | undefined; allowFullScreen?: boolean | undefined; ... 364 more ...; className: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
  Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.ts(2322)